# Detecting Windows Phone and Tablet clients

Tags: object-oriented, salesforce-apex

This is called from a VF page,

```
styleClass="{!IF(isWindows8Device, 'windows', 'not_windows')}"
```

So if it's a windows device, return true.

The best thing to do would be to add one method in DeviceDetectionCls to check for any windows device, instead of two methods.

For the purpose of this question though, I've to use both.

Could it be improved at all?

```
public Boolean isWindows8Device{    
    get{
         String userAgent = System.currentPageReference().getHeaders().get('User-Agent');                       

         if(DeviceDetectionCls.isWindows8Phone(userAgent)){
            return true;
         }

         if(DeviceDetectionCls.isWindows8Tablet(userAgent)){
            return true;
         }

         return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Our convention on Code Review is for titles to reflect the purpose of the code. Otherwise, a quarter of our site would be questions entitled "Too many if statements".

Comment: @200_success But I wasn't asking for help regarding 'Detecting Windows Phone and Tablet clients'. I wanted to improve the efficiency of the method. Which is why I accepted the answer by Josay.

Comment: That's fine. You can ask about the if statements within the body of the question. (Even if you didn't ask explicitly, the answer would probably have been similar.) But question titles need to be more distinctive than what you originally had.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess something like :

```
return DeviceDetectionCls.isWindows8Phone(userAgent) || DeviceDetectionCls.isWindows8Tablet(userAgent);
```

would do the trick.